# Magento 2.4.1 Disabling MSI Modules (responsible for inventory) after Upgrade to 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, php-7, magento2.4, elasticsearch

We have a Magentoshop (2.4.1) running with elastic-search. Because there is no need of any inventory-tracking, I disabled all the modules according to the following suggestions:

https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/inventory-management/

Also here is another suggestions for modules to disable:
https://meetanshi.com/blog/disable-magento-msi/

I get the following error, when running setup:upgrade:

```
Dependency declaration 'cataloginventory_stock' in 'catalogsearch_fulltext' to the non-existing indexer
```

That is obviously because of the dependency of the indexers, which is defined in the file:

```
vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/etc/indexer.xml
```

I tried to just remove the indexer from this file (via a composer-patch), but this doesn't help. Then I would get a mysql-error and I don't think it would be a good idea to fix the indexer itself. Any suggestions or help?

Comment: Your link explicitly quotes a method to disable all inventory modules for 2.4. I tried that and it works just fine on a fresh install of 2.4.1.